# How to check certain headers exist in each request in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to test `api_key` and `secret` against all requests of different models. Both fields exist in a table. I am using `DefaultRouter` which itself creates all CRUD based requests URLs. Will I need to create custom functions to check headers or there is some better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the name of headers, I assume you want to check those for authentication. Django REST Framework enables you to implement you custom authentication mechanism, you can check here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication

After creating your custom authentication, you can set it to be globally used on `settings.py` or on any endpoint individually.

Comment: Cool. I will look into it. So basically I can have a global method that will run and check API info against Db Table everytime before serve it?

Comment: Yep, it works just like that. If the authentication is successful, the user object will be accessible in the view as `request.user`.